# how to use a post method with a spring data rest process?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I'm using a repostiroy rest resource service and currently I need to implement a method to import the data from a excel file into my database. I don't see how I can do with spring repository rest resource? since it's an interface. do I use restController or does it have a way to do both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard flow would be:

1. Create a repository file

   ```
   @Repository
   public interface RepositoryClass extends JpaRepository<T, ID>{}
   ```

- where T is the class and ID is the data type of the ID (ex: Long, Integer etc.)

The JpaRepository already have save() and saveAll() methods([1](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html))

2. In service create a method that read the data and saves it in the database

   ```
   @Service
   public class ServiceClass{

   // ...some code

      public void importData(// ... parameters){
           // open the excel file and import the data in an ArrayList for exemple

           repositoryClass.saveAll(arrayWithData);
      }
   }
   ```
3. The last step is to create a endpoint in the controller which calls the method that is written in service.

Answer (score 0):

That interface have a method called `save()`. You can save the given object in database like: `repository.save(myOjbect)`